# Spring ACL: Implemented Krams Spring Security 3 tutorial and hasPermission is not being called

Tags: spring, spring-security

I followed the Krams Spring Security 3 tutorial to implement Spring ACL(the link: krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-security-3-full-acl-tutorial.html).  I basically cut an pasted his code into mine.  My hope was that I would have a working example to expand upon.  The code runs but the has permission method never gets called and no exceptions are thrown.

1. I am using Postgres 9 as my database.  I used the DDL from the Spring ACL documents to implement the schema.
2. My Spring Security configuration file looks like this:

   ```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:arg="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

     <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/public" access="hasRole('anonymousReader')" requires-channel="https" />
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/public/*" access="hasRole('anonymousReader')" requires-channel="https" />
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/bulletin/view" access="hasRole('anonymousReader')"/>
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/role/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/role/user" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/role/visitor" access="hasRole('anonymousReader')"/>

     <!-- URLs that are accessed by role/actions -->
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https" />

     <!-- Defines a custom role in place of ROLE_ANONYMOUS.  ROLE_ANONYMOUS will no more work, use ROLE_GUEST instead of it-->
     <security:anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="anonymousReader" />

     <!-- login/logout forms -->
     <security:form-login login-page="/public" default-target-url="/member/registerLogin"
               authentication-failure-url="/public/loginfailed" />
     <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/public" />
   </security:http>

   <security:authentication-manager alias="authManager">
     <!-- security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsServiceSparql" -->
     <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsServiceJPA">
       <!-- should the auth module go in the tripple store ??? -->
       <security:password-encoder hash="plaintext"/>
       <!-- security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/ -->
     </security:authentication-provider>
   </security:authentication-manager>

   <!-- bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/ -->

   <bean id="anonymousAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter" arg:key="guest" />

   <bean id="anonymousAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider" arg:key="guest" />
   </beans>
   ```
3. My Spring ACL configuration looks like this (other than changing the data source and changing the guest role to anonymous reader, this file was cut and pasted unchanged from the Krams tutorial.):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd">

   <!-- Enables method security with expression-based access control -->
   <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">

   <!-- Reference to a custom expression handler with ACL support -->
   <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
     </security:global-method-security>

     <!-- A customized expression handler
    permissionEvaluator: a reference to a custom PermissionEvaluator
    roleHierarchy: defines the role order -->
     <bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler"
   p:permissionEvaluator-ref="permissionEvaluator"
   p:roleHierarchy-ref="roleHierarchy" />

   <!-- A customized PermissionEvaluator that evaluates permissions via the ACL module -->
   <bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.AclPermissionEvaluator" id="permissionEvaluator">
     <!-- Reference to the ACL service which performs JDBC calls to an ACL database -->
     <constructor-arg ref="aclService"/>
   </bean>
   <!-- A customized ACL service which provides default JDBC implementation -->
   <bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService" id="aclService">
     <constructor-arg ref="connectionPoolDataSource"/>
     <constructor-arg ref="lookupStrategy"/>
     <constructor-arg ref="aclCache"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- A lookup strategy for optimizing database queries -->
   <bean id="lookupStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy">
     <constructor-arg ref="connectionPoolDataSource"/>
     <constructor-arg ref="aclCache"/>
     <constructor-arg ref="aclAuthorizationStrategy"/>
     <constructor-arg ref="auditLogger"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- An ACL cache to minimize calls to the ACL database -->   
   <bean id="aclCache" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.EhCacheBasedAclCache">
   <constructor-arg>
     <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
       <property name="cacheManager">
         <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"/>
       </property>
       <property name="cacheName" value="aclCache"/>
     </bean>
   </constructor-arg>
   </bean>

   <!-- An ACL authorization strategy to determine whether a principal is permitted to call administrative methods -->
   <bean id="aclAuthorizationStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl">
   <constructor-arg>
     <list>
       <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
         <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
       </bean>
       <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
           <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
       </bean>
       <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
         <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
       </bean>
     </list>
   </constructor-arg>
   </bean>

   <!-- An audit logger used to log audit events -->
   <bean id="auditLogger" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ConsoleAuditLogger"/>

   <!-- Defines the role order -->
   <!-- http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/hierarchicalroles/RoleHierarchyImpl.html -->
   <bean id="roleHierarchy"  class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
     <property name="hierarchy">
       <value>
           ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER
           ROLE_USER > anonymousReader
       </value>
     </property>
   </bean>
   </beans>
   ```
4. I load both files into the Spring context from the web.xml file. Both files are loaded sucessfully.  Here are the context params:

   ```
   <context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>
       WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
       WEB-INF/acl-context.xml,
       WEB-INF/spring-security-context.xml,
       WEB-INF/resources-context.xml
     </param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```
5. I changed his controllers to use tiles and made the services use in memory objects instead of going to the database.  The in memory objects have the expected long ID values.  Here are examples of the code.

   A. The bulletin controller:

   ```
   /**
   * Handles Bulletin related requests
   */
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/bulletin")
   public class BulletinController{

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("controller");

    @Resource(name="adminService")
    private GenericService adminService;

    @Resource(name="personalService")
    private GenericService personalService;

    @Resource(name="publicService")
    private GenericService publicService;

    /**
    * Retrieves the View page. 
    * <p>
    * This loads all authorized posts.
    */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/view", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getViewAllPage() {
      logger.debug("Received request to view all page");
      ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("bulletinPage");

      // Retrieve items from service and add to model
      model.addObject("adminposts", adminService.getAll());
      model.addObject("personalposts", personalService.getAll());
      model.addObject("publicposts", publicService.getAll());

      // Add our current role and username
      model.addObject("role", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities());
      model.addObject("username", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());

      // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/bulletinpage.jsp
      return model;
     }
   }
   ```

   B. The AdminService.getAll method. When this method is called it returns all of the admin posts.  The hasPermission method never gets called.  (The hasRole method gets called and is working correctly.)

   ```
   /**
   * Service for processing Admin related posts. 
   */
   @Service("adminService")
   @Transactional
   public class AdminService implements GenericService {

   protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("service");
   private Map<Long, Post> adminPosts;
   private int nextId;

   public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
     initializeAllPosts();
   }

   private void initializeAllPosts() {
     this.adminPosts = new HashMap<Long, Post>();
     this.adminPosts.put(new Long(1), initializePost(new Long(1), new Date(), "Custom post #1 from admin"));
     this.adminPosts.put(new Long(2), initializePost(new Long(2), new Date(), "Custom post #2 from admin"));
     this.adminPosts.put(new Long(3), initializePost(new Long(3), new Date(), "Custom post #3 from admin"));
     this.nextId = 4;
   }

   private AdminPost initializePost(Long id, Date date, String message) {
     AdminPost adminPost = new AdminPost();
     adminPost.setId(id);
     adminPost.setDate(date);
     adminPost.setMessage(message);
     return adminPost;
   }

   @PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'READ')")
   public List<Post> getAll() {
     try {
       logger.debug("Retrieving all admin posts");
       if(null == this.adminPosts) initializeAllPosts();

       List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<Post>();

       for(Post adminPost : this.adminPosts.values()) {
         posts.add(adminPost);
       }

       return posts;

     } catch (Exception e) {
       logger.error(e);
       return null;
     } 
   }
   }
   ```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.